# How to perform action on popup. it's displayed randomly in between of some actions? Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

```
case "single select type":
radioButtonStatus = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Single select type')]")).isDisplayed();
Random random=new Random();
int number=random.nextInt(5);
if(number==0)
{
  number=number+1;
}
if (radioButtonStatus)
{
  System.out.println("RadioButton"+number);
  webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("path["+number+"]path/*[1]")).click();
  Exam.clickOnSaveandNextButton();
}
break;
```

I have written a loop with a switch case. If the loop is 60 times then the popup will appear in between the loop at different points.

Comment: Sorry..I cannot help because you never responds to any of the answers.

Comment: @NandanA : Agreed! but at the same time, OP may not be aware of accepting/upvoting answers.

Comment: Sai - Please go through this meta post https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @cruisepandey Hey... Thanks for your support.

Comment: @NandanA I have responded to answers but Stack members saying that "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @selenium Please help out........... I got struckedup  here